# What will be the expiration date of my I-94 if I re-enter from Mexico after previously visiting the US?

Tags: visas, usa, i-94

I hold a B-1 visa set to expire on 23rd Sep, and I-94 set to expire on 26th Sep. I plan to go to mexico on Sep 14th and return on 17th. Upon my return, will i be allowed to re -enter? What would potentially be  my new I-94 expiry?

Comment: As I understand it there's a good chance you'd be readmitted until the 26th, but you might be able to talk your way into a new six-month period.  On the other hand, if your plans for your time in the US are not well defined, or if you raise the proverbial red flag for any other reason, such as the amount of time you've recently spent in the US, you might be denied entry altogether.  Without knowing these details, it's difficult to give a useful answer to your question.  Can you add them?

Comment: Are you visiting Mexico by land?  The CBP officers at the Mexico border (particularly in Tijuana) are very picky about your onward travel plans if your visa or ESTA are due to expire.  An I94 can be renewed at the border for $6 (prepare to wait in line for this) but only if they are satisfied with your visa renewal or onward travel plans.

Comment: B1 is business visitor visa. When you return, will it still be for business purposes? Or do you mean B2?

Comment: @Midavalo the expiration of the visa isn't an issue in the least.  The problem will be the recent visit, as well as, possibly, the purpose of the visit.

Comment: The question will be why do you want to re-enter?  Are you likely to overstay?  They will want to know a lot about your onward travel plans and how you plan to vacate USA timely.  If you are eligible for an extension they will want to know *that you know that* and will want to know that your plans don't rely on approval you haven't gotten yet.

Comment: @phoog - i hold a domestic helper visa. Helping my single parent employer with her son. Her name is attached to my visa. This is my secod travel to mexico for a vacation woth my employer and her son. First one was march 22 2017. We returned/re entry march 26. My i94 was approved until 27th sep that time. Now we will go out again on 14th sep and come back 17th sep. She is a single parent and holds an L1 visa i29s with expiry 2018 july.

Comment: @harper -- i want to reenter to continue to help my single parent employer with her son. She is all alone here in the US. My visa is annotated with my employer's name, and she is very strict to let me go home within approved times. She is careful to make sure we follow rules as her visa also is annotated with her company's name. I will vacate US timely as i have a return ticket already bought.

Comment: @Midavalo -- i will travel by air.

Comment: @Phoog --- u mentioned that visa expiry does not matter at all. Wanted to know if by any chance, u have heard of same situation that got i94 beyond visa expiry date?

Comment: @Feline517 it's very common for I-94s to extend beyond the visa expiration date.  The visa only needs to be valid on the date of *entry* into the US.  Even then, there are exceptions thanks to automatic revalidation where you can reenter the US with an expired visa within 30 days after leaving, subject to certain other conditions.

Comment: @phoog --- when i re enter, what documentation will i need to show? Passport, visa, i94? Are there others?

Comment: You don't necessarily need your I-94, since your visa will be valid when you return, and you will not need to depend on automatic revalidation.  On what date were you admitted with the September 26th stamp?

Comment: @phoog - admitted march 27th 2017.

Comment: @phoog - letting u know i was re-accepted.  Thank you for the answers you provided. Your answers were very helpful and made me more confident re- entering. I was allowed to stay until 18 march 2018 even if visa was only until 18th september and i94 before this re enter was only until 26th sep 2017.

Comment: @Feline517 Thanks for coming back and letting us know!  Please post that information as an answer.  Then you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It's very common for I-94s to extend beyond the visa expiration date. The visa only needs to be valid on the date of entry into the US. Even then, there are exceptions, thanks to automatic revalidation where you can reenter the US with an expired visa within 30 days after leaving, subject to certain other conditions.